# How to locate and click svg class in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, class, svg, findelement

I'm trying to locate the svg class element to be able to move to the next page of the website and be able to make a list of all the pages. Unfortunetly, the only thing I can locate in this element appears to be too complicated for me. I've tried locating it by XPATX and went through different tips here on stack but still can't python cant find it.

Here is the html from the page:

```
> <a data-testid="pagination-forward" data-cy="pagination-forward" href="/d/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/wynajem/wroclaw/?page=2&amp;search%5Bfilter_enum_rooms%5D%5B0%5D=two&amp;search%5Bprivate_business%5D=private">
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="1em" height="1em" class="css-pyu9k9">
> <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7 2v1.414l1.271 1.27L15.586 12l-7.315 7.315L7 20.585V22h1.414l1.27-1.271L17 13.414l1-1v-.827l-3.942-3.942v-.001L9.686 3.271 8.413 2z"></path></svg></a>
```

What should I try to locate it? Thanks in advance

I've been trying using XPATH locator and different tips from stack

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I can find it by class easily, thought if in HTML was coded "SVG class" it's different type of class.